# Set a childByAutoId value in Firebase data service class to be retrieved in another class

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hopefully I can make this more clear than my title. I created a FirebaseService class. In it I will create all of the methods for saving and retrieving data. I don't want to have to make a firebase reference in any other class. I simply want to reference this class to do that. If this isn't possible, please let me know so I don't move forward with it. Below is my FirebaseService class...

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FirebaseService: NSObject {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var id = String()


    func savePost(post:[String:AnyObject]) {
        let postRef = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId()
        id = postRef.key
        postRef.setValue(post)

    }



}
```

I want to be able to retrieve `id` from the FirebaseService class and have it actually use the value of childByAutoId (the post's randomly generated id in Firebase) when I save a post so I can save it as a value in post called "id". However, right now when I save it, I get an intended random id generated for the post as a whole but I don't get that value in my "id" key.

```
func postPost() {
    post.id = FirebaseService().id
    post.textContent = textView.text
    post.name = "Michael Williams"
    post.profileImageName = "cool"
    post.imageContentName = "coffee"
    post.createdDate = convertCurrentTimeToString()
    let postArray:[String:AnyObject] = ["name":post.name!, "profileImageName":post.profileImageName!, "textContent":post.textContent!, "imageContentName":post.imageContentName!, "createdDate":post.createdDate!, "id":post.id!]
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        FirebaseService().savePost(postArray)
    }
}
```

Firebase database scheme:

- Posts   "randomly generated id"

  - name: "John Doe"
  - id: same randomly generated id as above
  - postText: "Blah Blah"

Again, all I am getting for id is an empty string when I run the `postPost()` function.

Comment: General rule of thumb is you should be using 'self' within a closure. So self.id = postRef.key

Comment: Also, I think the logic here isn't going to work (reliably). If you call postPost() it's assigning a post.id = FirebaseService.id, but it's doing that *before* the actual savePost is called, which generates that id. Also, why are you doing the assignments to post to then stuffing it into an array using the same values you just used? Why not just = ["name": "Michael Williams, "profileImageName": "cool" etc

Comment: Oh, and to answer your question: yes, you can call functions in other classes. If they are going to be static, I would recommend creating a file called Constants.swift and keep your singleton-like functions, structures etc in that file. If your case, the id variable is of some interest but it's not clear from your question what you want to do with it, so using a Constants.swift may not be a good solution.

Comment: If I set the id property of posts at the time when its generated, I can pass that data between views without having to know the uid myself. I can also use that uid to create reference connections to other properties. I get that the logic is wrong (If it was correct, I wouldn't be on here asking about it). What I am looking for is a solution. I need to be able to set the id property to the posts uid without having to make a separate call to Firebase when I add a new post.

Comment: uid would be the user id. I think you mean the key. Are you observing the posts ref for .ChildAdded events to notify you when posts are added? That will determine the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is savePost is what sets the id value in FirebaseService. Your attempting to assign the value of the id before the savePost function gets called and assigns keys value to id.

Try having your savePost function take a Post object as the argument, then set up its format to uploaded to Firebase in that function. It will allow you to set the Post.id from the reference you create in that function.

```
func postPost() {
//remove line assigned post.id
post.textContent = textView.text
post.name = "Michael Williams"
post.profileImageName = "cool"
post.imageContentName = "coffee"
post.createdDate = convertCurrentTimeToString()
//Remove postArray
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
    FirebaseService().savePost(post)
}}
```

Assign post.id in savePost function:

```
func savePost(post: Post) {
    let postRefKey = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId()
    //Get key
    let postRef = ref.child("posts")
    //Generate base reference to all posts
    post.id = postRefKey
    let postDict = ["postId": post.id, "postName" : post.name] //etc
    //save post to postsReference using the generate key and then set that keys value to Post Object
    postRef.child(postRefKey).setValue(postDict)


}
```

Another way you could do it is with a closure using a completion block.

```
func savePost(post: Post, completion: String -> Void) {
//savePostFunctionHere
let key = postRefKey
completion(key)
}

func postPost() {
//remove line assigned post.id
post.textContent = textView.text
post.name = "Michael Williams"
post.profileImageName = "cool"
post.imageContentName = "coffee"
post.createdDate = convertCurrentTimeToString()
//Remove postArray
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
FirebaseService().savePost(post, completion: { postId in
post.id = postId
})
}}
```

If you aren't familiar with closures, in the savePost function you assign the refKey or Postkey to the completion argument, then when you call the function and it is completed, you get the id back and you are able to do whatever you want with it, in this case, assign it to post.id.

This way is better if you want to keep everything else as how you had it before because this will still work without having to change much else around.

Answer (score -1):

**I believe I misread your code. My bad. Here's my new answer.**

I think you want to set

```
post["id"] = postRef.key
```

Before you call

```
postRef.setValue(post)
```

Comment: The id is going to be a string either way; e.g. it could just as easily be id = "". The OP needs that id to be the *key* generated from Firebase, not a NSUUID string, and it's being assigned to another variable before it's created (see my comment). This answer doesn't address the question nor does it really provide any kind of solution.

Comment: Jay, I answered correctly at the top of my answer. I will edit out the other irrelevant details to make it clearer.